# How to open mongojs editor

Tags: mongojs

OS: Windows7

I installed mongojs using the "npm install mongojs" command. Now, how do I open the mongo.js editor using node.js or cygwin?

I googled and youtubed this all day and it seems like a taboo subject. I've successfully created mongodb (localhost:28017) and able to make simple commands using node.js.

Manny